# Saving data from SPSS to Excel - custom sheet name

Tags: python, excel, spss, worksheet

Is it possible, When exporting a dataset from SPSS to Excel, to control the name of the worksheet the data is being saved into ? The "SAVE TRANSLATE OUTFILE" command does not allow for this. I have SPSS 21, with Python installed (although I am fairly new to Python...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See this [weblink](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21610825) on IBM website for details.

```
get file="C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\23\Samples\English\Employee data.sav".

SAVE TRANSLATE 
  /TYPE=ODBC
  /CONNECT='DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=C:\Daten\Temp\EmployeeDataExcelExport.xlsx;'
  /ENCRYPTED
  /MISSING=IGNORE
  /REPLACE
  /TABLE='EmployeeData'.
```

### EDIT:

The syntax provided in the link on IBM website does NOT work for me however the below does:

```
save translate
    /connect="dsn=excel files;dbq=C:\Temp\EmployeeDataExcelExport.xls;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;"
    /table="EmployeeData"
    /type=odbc /map /replace.
```

---

Comment: What bit version SPSS do you have? What bit version MS office do you have?

Comment: I am using SPSS 21 64 bits, Office 365... 32 bits; just realized this now. So yeah... will have to do it manually.

Comment: There you go! As Jon pointed out this has to be a match. There are no work arounds. But why do you have a mismatch? If this type of operation (save translate) is important, regularly used, then you could/should just install 32bit SPSS. Benefits of 64bit would be negligible (unless you are regularly working on very large datasets) over ODBC connection, I would presume.

Comment: I've had to make this comprise in the past also when only 32bit Office was available to us but we were running 64 bit OS and SPSS. But the ODBC direct connection with SPSS was judge to be far more important. You'll have to asses on your needs.

Comment: Installing another version of office or SPSS would compromise other things; I guess I can live with it as it is; I did test your solution, though, and it works

Answer (score 2):

SAVE TRANSLATE relies on ODBC drivers, which means that your Statistics and Office bitness has to match - 64-bit Statistics with 32-bit Office won't work.  Otherwise, you can write to an Excel file with SAVE TRANSLATE and then use VBA automation via a Basic script in Statistics to rename the sheet.  There is a Basic module available from the SPSS Community website that writes output tables to an Excel file that does some sheet renaming that you could adapt for your purposes.

You can find the module here
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/app?lang=en#/file/8e0dfcb6-aa57-4639-a20e-1780010cfe83